# Flask SQLAlchemy foreign key contraint incorrectly malformed

Tags: python, flask

I wrote the following code:

```
class User(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    first_name = db.Column(db.String(255), nullable=True)
    last_name = db.Column(db.String(255), nullable=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(255), unique=True, nullable=False)

    password_expires_at = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=False)
    active = db.Column(db.Boolean, nullable=False)

    created_at = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=False,
        default=datetime.utcnow)
    updated_at = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=False,
        default=datetime.utcnow)

    session_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('session.id'),
        nullable=False)

class Session(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.String(255), primary_key=True)
    ip = db.Column(db.String(255), unique=True, nullable=False)
    user = db.relationship('User', backref='session')

db.create_all()
```

When running Flask I get the following error:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (MySQLdb._exceptions.OperationalError) (1005, 'Can\'t create table `bugbot`.`user` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")')
[SQL: 
CREATE TABLE user (
        id INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
        first_name VARCHAR(255), 
        last_name VARCHAR(255), 
        email VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, 
        password_expires_at DATETIME NOT NULL, 
        active BOOL NOT NULL, 
        created_at DATETIME NOT NULL, 
        updated_at DATETIME NOT NULL, 
        session_id INTEGER NOT NULL, 
        PRIMARY KEY (id), 
        UNIQUE (email), 
        CHECK (active IN (0, 1)), 
        FOREIGN KEY(session_id) REFERENCES session (id)
)

]
```

I followed a tutorial to get to this code so I don't know what I'm doing wrong. Could anyone help me out?

Comment: did you define the primary key for the table?

Comment: Pleas include a link to the tutorial.
And could you try this:
user = db.relationship('User', backref='session', lazy=True)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The column you are trying to place constraint on (`User.session_id`) is of type `Integer` whereas the column it is referencing (`Session.id`) is of type `String`! That's why it is failing, make both types compatible and run it again, it should work.